# How to set focus on next control when user presses enter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, setfocus

I am developing an asp.net web site for that I need a custom text-box control. In that text-box when ever user clicks on enter button it should set focus on next control of web form. How can I force it to set focus on next control in form using javascript?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Most users will expect TAB to move between form inputs, and ENTER to submit the form.